# Custom reshaping layer return Tensor with shape (?,?,?)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm, reshape

I need a layer that reshapes a 4D Tensor from a Convolutional layer with shape (None, 3, 3, 2048) to a 3D Tensor with shape (None, 9, 2048) to be fed into an LSTM, where 9 is the size of the timesteps dimension.

When I use the layer itself it works, but when I use it in a Sequential model, the next layer gets (?,?,?) as `input_shape` from the output of my custom layer.

Below you can find my code:

```py
class Conv2LSTM(Layer):

    '''The :class:`Conv2LSTM` is a custom layer that reshapes the input tensor collapsing the width and height dimensions to a single dimension that represents the sequence accepted by the LSTM.
    '''

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Conv2LSTM, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.input_spec = [InputSpec(shape=input_shape)]
        super(Conv2LSTM, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, x, mask=None):

        '''Overrides the :class:`keras.engine.topology.Layers` method. It collapses the second and third dimension of the tensor into a single dimension.

        :param x: input tensor
        :param mask: tensor mask
        :return: re-ordered tensor
        '''

        return K.reshape(x, (K.shape(x)[0],) + (K.shape(x)[1]*K.shape(x)[2], K.shape(x)[3]))

    def get_config(self):
        base_config = super(Conv2LSTM, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()))

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0],) + (input_shape[1]*input_shape[2], input_shape[3])
```

How is it possible that if I print the shape inside the layer it is correct, if I create a model with that single layer it works, but combined with a successive layer, it returns a NoneType shape?

Answer (score 0):

For some reasons, while in every answer from other similar questions it is suggested to use `K.shape(x)` to retrieve the shape of the input tensor, in this case, the error was caused by that.

It was sufficient to replace `K.shape(x)[i]` with `x.shape[i].value`.

The new implementation of `call` is:

`return K.reshape(x, (-1, x.shape[1].value * x.shape[2].value, x.shape[3].value))`